# Install Macos from recovery using Bootable USB

Tags: macos, bootcamp, usb

I have replaced my broken HDD with a new SSD and I can't install Mac from recovery (Command+R) no matter what connection I try to connect to, I tried different networks (router via Wifi, router via Ethernet, 4G Hotspot) I mostly got Error -1005F and sometimes -2105F.

The only option left was that I download High Sierra 10.13.2 dmg file from a trusted source and I created a bootable USB using TransMac, with the only problem being, it doesn't recognize the USB (though formatted as GPT), if I restart the Macbook holding option key, it only shows a box to connect to Wifi, there are no disks to choose to boot from, I tried a USB 3.0 and a USB 2.0 devices, both didn't work.

Any idea how I can troubleshoot?

Is there a better way to install mac on my macbook pro 2011? (High Sierra compatible)

I also removed the optical drive from Macbook a while ago, installing Mac from a DVD wouldn't be an option for me.

Comment: Why did you not create the USB installer by using these instructions: ["How to create a bootable installer for macOS"](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)?

Comment: High Sierra is macOS 10.13.X. Why do you have High Sierra 10.12.2 for your dmg file? Why did you not download from the App Store? What version of macOS did you have installed on the old drive?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Oh, sorry, It was a typo, I fixed it to 10.13.2 and I don't have any other device that runs MacOS in my household nor I know of anyone who has a Macbook (I'm kind of a loner) So I can't download the OS from App store.

Comment: Error 1005f means that your Internet connection is not "good enough" (low bandwidth, perhaps).  It doesn't matter if you use WiFi or Ethernet, if you don't have enough bandwidth from the router out, it won't work.  Try another network altogether (school, work, etc.)  If you are close to an Apple store, go there and they will assist with downloading the image for you.

Comment: @Allan I tried connectify on windows and shared my internet and it worked I don't even know how that could make a difference, (the connection was tunneled)

Comment: A tunneled connection has a defacto "keep alive" that doesn't allow it to drop. It may be the connection "drops" when not in use and doesn't come back quickly enough for Internet Recovery to be successful.  The "live" connection facilitated by the tunnel may have solved it.  Let us know if you get macOS installed.

Comment: Also...see this answer on creating a bootable USB once you have everything up and running:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234754/can-recovery-mode-install-os-x-onto-a-blank-ssd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: These instructions assume that the only internal drive is a SSD.

The procedure given below may seem lengthy, but once completed, you will not have to preform this procedure again. After installing 10.13.3, you will be able to reinstall the current version of macOS directly from Internet Recovery.

1. Boot to  Internet Recovery
2. Use the Disk Utility app to initialize the SSD for `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`.
3. Install 10.7.5.
4. Boot to 10.7.5.
5. Download 10.13.3 installer app from the App Store. If this is not possible, then first upgrade to 10.11.6.
6. [Transfer the 10.13.3 installer app to a USB flash drive.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)
7. Boot from the flash drive.
8. Use the Disk Utility app to initialize the SSD for `APFS` or `APFS (Encrypted)`.
9. Install 10.13.3
10. Boot to 10.13.3