# Install OS for new SSD

Tags: ssd, mojave

I bought a new SSD for my old macbook pro mid 2012.
Can I clone my current OS on other Macbook to SSD and bring it to my old Macbook 2012?
Thank you!

Comment: Why not try [Recovery Mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234786/119271) to install a fresh OS?

Comment: It depends on OSX, you might need to format the disk with APFS format for Mojave. Then you can use Recover from time machine, use CCC app, use Apple Recovery or Internet recovery ....

Comment: We have dozens of questions covering this ground. If you don't see your specific situation covered in the linked / related, please edit this to show a little research or setup to explain how the guides to install MacOS on to an external drive don't work for you. Basically, you want to install the OS before you swap the hardware for the best results. Split the problem into two - don't do the surgery until you're sure you have a bootable / valid SSD and OS.

Comment: You cant also use target disk mode w/ migration assistant to import your account