# Running iMac 2009 on external screen due to Broken LCD

Tags: display, hard-drive, imac

So I would like to know if it is possible to diagnose and install new OSX using blank SSD in an iMac that has broken LCD and no hard drive?

I bought this iMac out of auction where you cant test anything and buy as-is, and looks like I'm in deep trouble as the display doesn't work and it has no hard drive. The iMac chimes with Apple sound when turned on so that tells me motherboard is working.

Comment: What model of iMac, please.

Comment: Do you have any other Macs which can be used to put macOS on the SSD?

Comment: @IconDaemon its 27" iMac 2009 or 2010 model

Comment: @DavidAnderson no this is my first ever mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to diagnose and install macOS on an iMac with a broken LCD and missing hard drive.

The iMac all-in-ones from that vintage has a mini Display Port for a second display.  It supports Leopard through El Capitan.  Here’s what you’ll need at a minimum:

- A mini display port to VGA, DVI, or HDMI adapter, depending on the monitor you’re hooking up to.
- A bootable USB - either an installer or a USB with a full installation on it.  You can create an installer by following [one of the many guides](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234786/119271) found online.  If you want to use the full install, you’ll need to install macOS to a USB flash (64GB is sufficient) or a USB hard drive.

As for a keyboard, I’m assuming it comes with one, but if it doesn’t, you don’t need an Apple one; a cheap USB keyboard will work fine. Just remember, the “Windows” and “Alt” keys are the <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> keys, respectively.

Comment: Makes so much sense. So the followup question is does the bootloader automatically shifts to second monitor connected by VGA or HDMI or the operating system has to be loaded first and from there we can use maybe a keyboard shortcut? I mean to say that when the power button is pressed, will iMac automatically show the boot options which are necessary to install the OSX into external monitor?

Comment: It will mirror, by default, the same way a PC does.

Comment: @Allan: Is there something special about 2009 iMacs? I ask because I currently have a 2007 iMac with a second monitor connected using a DVI jack. When I boot from a USB El Capitan installer, the displays do **not** mirror. I can drag the initial window to the second monitor, but the initial window does not appear by default on the second monitor. Also the menu bar remains on the builtin display regardless of where the initial window resides. Opening the Disk Utility results in the Disk Utility appearing only on the builtin display.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I don’t know about special, but I did this exact thing with a 2010 iMac I bought from a government surplus store that had a physically broken LCD

Comment: @Allan looks like we are on the same boat. I also purchased from the government discarded items auction :)

Comment: Here’s to hoping you are as lucky with your purchase as I was!  :-)

Comment: My comment was wrt a 2006 iMac with an internal display that is going bad. Like the 2007, the 2006 does not mirror when an external display is connected. If Allan is correct, then all I would have to do is disconnect the internal display and this would cause the external display to become the main display.

Comment: @DavidAnderson im not sure that disconnecting the internal display will switch the logic to automatically make external display as main display. But if the cost is not a burden then we can always give it a try.

Comment: @Allan please see if [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389361/will-gpu-from-imac-21-5-work-on-imac-27-for-2010-2011-models) could be of value.

Comment: I actually started researching it yesterday because it piqued my interest.  I don’t know the answer, but I’ll try to find out