# Select the disk where you want to install macOS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive, install, ssd

I am trying to revive my mid-2015 MacBook Pro.

I installed a new SSD, but when I go through the process of Reinstall macOS, I do not get the new SSD as a choice, it seems like I would have to install a 16GB USB flash drive and store it there.

It also does not seem to recognize the old SSD inside the enclosure that is connected to the MacBook.

I would like to follow the guide below

[Can Recovery Mode install OS X onto a blank SSD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234754/can-recovery-mode-install-os-x-onto-a-blank-ssd)
but how would I do this if all I can do is install the macOS Sierra on a flash drive?

I tried going into the terminal and running `diskutil list`, but my SSD is not found among the long list. It is a 480GB SSD and nothing in that list even comes close.

I installed macOS Sierra on a 16GB USB flash drive, but when I follow this guide:
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-mac-os-x-using-removable-usb-drive/

But when I click Option + Power it does go into installer, but then when I go to install from the USB flash drive, it tells me I do not have enough space. I don't get it, I already have macOS Sierra on that flash drive, what is it trying to do?

Comment: Did you try formatting the sss in diskutility first?

Comment: What make / model SSD? How is it connected to your mac?

Comment: @Scottmeup, the SSD is an Aura Pro X2 I installed it, removed the old SSD.

Comment: @DanRan, I did not know about that step, but I did not see Erase or Partition button as available, only first aid button.

Comment: @DanRan, the problem with running `diskutil list` is that my new SSD is not listed. Its a 480GB SSD and there is nothing close to 480GB listed in `diskutil list`. I will add this info to my OP.

Comment: @Daniel Then either your new ssd is botched/incompatable/or improperly installed. Try plugging it into an external enclosure first and then seeing if it shows up in disk utility. then try formatting.

Comment: @DanRan, I did try plugging it into an external enclosure and it still does not show up in disk utility. its definitely properly installed. So its either incompatible or botched, but could this also happen if the logic board is shot? I am out of ideas, its a brand new SSD. Is there a way to check that its NOT the new SSD?

Comment: @Daniel > Is there a way to check that its NOT the new SSD: You could put a known working+compatible SSD in. I guess that brings up the question: why are you replacing the old SSD?

Comment: @Scottmeup, the laptop is toast somehow, the battery pack is swollen for some reason. So I wanted to remove the old SSD so the repair people do not destroy my data and for me to figure out a way to recover whats in the old SSD, which will probably prompt a future question on how to do that.

Comment: @Daniel, To start your basic diagnostics you can install your ssd, then use apple hardware test over the internet. Per apples website: "Press and hold Option-D at startup to use Apple Diagnostics over the internet". That should tell you if you have any obvious hardware problems. Reference: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731  . If that doesn't give you any info, then you need to try installing it on another computer via external usb case, or internal. Try using a PC as well as another mac. If it doesnt show up on any other computer, youve got a botched ssd.

Comment: @DanRan, could I also try this process with the old SSD to get access to my data?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, Just repeat the above steps with any hard drive and you will be able to narrow down the issue. Diagnostics Tool>ThenInstallonPC>ThenInstallonAdifferentmac>thentryinstalling with external enclosure on both pc and different mac. If it doesnt appear on any of those, its a botched ssd.

Comment: @Daniel did you final get to format your Aura Pro X2 480GB SSD and install a new system on to it? Am having the same problem as you.

Comment: @GingerMacBenn, I had a professional install my Aura Pro X2 SSD for me. I also had the additional problem that my battery pack was damaged so I needed a whole new battery pack and keyword as well as installing a new SSD. I still have the old SSD that I need to figure out how to get my data out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specs sheet on the manufacturer's site for the [Aura Pro X2](https://www.owcshop.eu/catalog/product_info.php/aura-macbook-retina-late-2013-till-2015-480gb-p-1521) list macOS 10.13 High Sierra as the minimum compatible version.

The manufacturer recommends upgrading to macOS 10.13 High Sierra prior to installation. If that isn't possible I'd try using a USB installer for macOS 10.13 or higher as outlined [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).

Comment: I think the issue is knowledge gap when it comes to USB installer. I did install macOS on a USB flash drive, is that what everyone refers to as a USB installer? If so, do I follow Allan in this guide: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234754/can-recovery-mode-install-os-x-onto-a-blank-ssd

Comment: @Daniel I added a link to the Apple supported method of creating a USB installer. If you have issues with that you might want to try one of the unsupported methods, eg. http://dosdude1.com/software.html

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to format your newly installed ssd before the macos installer recognizes it as a viable medium to install your os on. If you cant format it in disk utility, try going to internet recovery and selecting the terminal. once in the terminal type

`diskutil list`

Then find the your newly installed disk drive labeled in the format of `/dev/diskX`where "X" is whatever disk number your new ssd is. This will most likely be `/dev/disk0` or `/dev/disk1`.

Once you have identified your disk number in the terminal, you can erase and format your new sdd by running the command

`diskutil eraseDisk apfs MacHD GPT /dev/diskX`

Dont forget to substitute the "X" in "/dev/diskX" with your real disk number.

For example, if your new ssd shows up in the terminal as `/dev/disk0`, the command to properly format it would be:

```
diskutil eraseDisk apfs MacHD GPT /dev/disk0
```

After that your new ssd should show up as an option in the mac installer application and you should be able to install macOS on it.