# Updating firmware to get OWC Aura Pro X2 SSD to show via Macbook Air

Tags: high-sierra, ssd, firmware

Basically I am trying to install a brand new Aura Pro X2 480gb SSD into a Macbook Air 2014, the original apple SSD has failed and is not seen by the Macbook Air. I know the Aura Pro X2 requires High Sierra as the previous system so the firmware updates via the Macbook Air.

But for some reason whenever I try to install High Sierra using a bootable installer via the Macbook Air, I get an error message stating that the computer is missing firmware partition on any device. I try to install High Sierra on to, been it a USB key or an external hard drive etc.

Is there anyway I can get High Sierra installed via a USB or external hard drive so the firmware partition updates, so I can then see the new Auro Pro X2 480gb SSD and install new system on to it?

I've tried formatting USB keys and hard drives in different ways but keep getting the missing firmware partition message on anything I do.

I have an old 2008 Mac Pro and also a 2011 Mac mini, if those can be useful in anyway to solving this issue I have.

Comment: Is the Aura Pro X2 480gb SSD installed into the MacBook Air? If not, then where?

Comment: I've tried with the Auro Pro X2 installed in Macbook Air and also without it when trying to install High Sierra on to either a USB key or external hard drive.

The Macbook Air does't see the Auro Pro X2 via disk util, as the firmware needs to be updated.

Comment: What was the newest version of macOS installed on the original apple SSD?

Comment: Had either 10.10 or 10.11 not sure as did't have the macbook air when working on Apple ssd.

Comment: You might try reading the accepted answer to the question [Select the disk where you want to install macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/409560/select-the-disk-where-you-want-to-install-macos) The same  Aura Pro X2 SSD is involved.

Comment: As in format the Auro SSD via disk utility, via internet recovery and use terminal to format?

Answer (score 0):

The OWC [installation video](https://eshop.macsales.com/installvideos/macbook_air_2013_2014/) has the following caution message.

[image: video]

High Sierra has a firmware update. To install this update, there needs to be an working internal drive compatible with the existing firmware. The original apple SSD was compatible. The new Aura Pro X2 480gb SSD will be compatible once the firmware update is installed.

I assume you have not ever had High Sierra or a newer version of macOS installed on your Mac. I assume this true, because you state the Disk Utility on the High Sierra installer does not recognize the new Aura Pro X2 480gb SSD when installed in your Mac.

Trying to install High Sierra to an external drive does not solve your problem. The firmware that updates itself requires an internal drive.

Comment: So is my only option to buy an used Apple SSD to update the firmware?

Comment: Ok I've obtained an Apple SSD and installed Mojave via the macbook air. But once the Aura Pro X2 is installed into the macbook air, the Mojave USB installer does't see new SSD via disk utilities.

Comment: Did you select `Show All Devices`?

Comment: do you mean via disk utitlies?

Comment: does't show in show all devices. i feel I may have defective Aura Pro X2 SSD.

Comment: The [instructions](https://eshop.macsales.com/tech_center/formatting/Format_OS_AuraProX2_Rev1.pdf) use Internet Recovery instead of a USB. I do not think that should make a difference. This [webpage](https://eshop.macsales.com/installvideos/macbook_air_2015_ssd/MacBookAir6-2/) instructs to peel the thin plastic liner off the top of the thermal pad. This is not mentioned in the installation video. Otherwise, you may be right about a defective Aura Pro X2 SSD. You could also try contacting [customer support](https://eshop.macsales.com/Service/support).

Comment: recovery would not boot. There is no thin plastic liner on the thermal pad, checked mag glass. I will contact support but now think have defective ssd.

Comment: Would not a missing plastic liner indicate you were shipped a used drive? Or, at least a drive that was returned by another customer?

Comment: Could indicate, but the box/packaging was all sealed. Plus the instructions included with SSD don't mention the thin plastic liner either. I think I will return the drive.