# I can't update to Mac OS 10.13 and later. You may not install to this volume because the computer is missing a firmware partition

Tags: macos, disk-utility, high-sierra, ssd, install

I have a 2015 MacBook Air 13 running macOS Sierra. I got it without a working internal SSD. Now it only runs on an external SSD via USB cable. I would like to upgrade to High Sierra, but an error prevents me from doing so.

The SSD is split into 2 partitions:

1 partition is in APFS format, and when I try to install on it I get an error that I need macOS Journaled format.

The 2nd partition is in macOS Journaled format, and when I try to install to it I get an error: "You may not install to this volume because the computer is missing a firmware partition".

In recovery mode, I am prompted to install macOS El Capitan.
I have tried so many methods from the internet, but have not found a solution.

The purpose of my upgrade to at least 10.13 is to support NVMe. I bought an m2 SSD, and an adapter to connect the SSD (Apple has its own connector for m2 SSD, which is different from the usual PCI-E). Now my MacBook can't see the internal SSD. Maybe if someone knows how to solve the problem differently, I won't need to upgrade to High Sierra.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: I would recommend reading [this question and answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/414002/updating-firmware-to-get-owc-aura-pro-x2-ssd-to-show-via-macbook-air).

Comment: I looked but never found a solution there. The author said he bought a used original SSD. I unfortunately don't have that option. Also, even when I upgraded to 10.13 he didn't see the SSD. 
Anyway thanks for the help!)