# Successfully installed macOS Sierra on USB flash drive, now what?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, install, ssd

My mid-2015 MacBook Pro crashed. I replaced the SSD with an Aura Pro X2, but I was not able to install macOS Sierra to it, but I was able to install macOS Sierra to a 16GB USB flash drive.

But now what do I do with that flash drive? How do I get the OS installed on my hard drive?

Would I have to go back to Terminal and run the command that Allan gives in this post?
[Can Recovery Mode install OS X onto a blank SSD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234754/can-recovery-mode-install-os-x-onto-a-blank-ssd)

Comment: Why do you keep abandoning one question & start another, when all these issues are clearly tied together? Did the answers to your last question not lead you in the right direction? Presumably you managed to find the solution to your first issue - why not post an answer?

Comment: @Tetsujin, I have not received a working answer. I was trying not to take advantage of getting more than one answer. There are two issues going on and yes they are related. One is my MacBook is not recognizing this brand new SSD, but if I try to install from USB flash drive, I am not getting that done successfully either and I am unclear if there is a knowledge gap in the USB flash drive approach. So I thought it warranted two separate questions. If you disagree, I guess I can remove this one. Then there is the question, if the logic board is shot, does any of this be pulled off?

Comment: Installing the OS on a flash drive is not the same as setting up the flash drive as an installer. All I can tell from the 3 questions so far is you still haven't got this new SSD to show up in any way, shape or form. Until that happens, there's nowhere else to go. Based on info in the other question, you needed to have High Sierra on the Mac **first** otherwise you don't have the necessary firmware to be able to boot from APFS. Suggest putting the old drive back & getting HS on it before pursuing this.

Comment: @Tetsujin, thank you for getting back to me. Yeah the old SSD is not being recognized by my MacBook, it never finishes loading when I go into Disk Utility with it. Does that mean the logic board is shot and its time to find a Genius?

Comment: It means nothing more than one isn't communicating with the other. If you have 2 SSDs with the same symptom, it's time to send it to a repair shop for their opinion. It could be the mobo, it could just be the SATA cable.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I thank you, I think I will go ahead and send it to a repair shop for their opinion. Feel free to post your last comment as the answer. I plan to accept it as I feel I have tried everything else and as you say I have two SSDs with the same symptom.

Comment: I just realised that Mac doesn't have cabled SATA, it's a direct plug-in - so yup, repair shop.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I just dropped it off and they noticed something I failed to mention simply because I did not know what was going on, but the battery to a MacBook is the hard black pillowing things, well I did notice they were swollen but did not know what to make of it. The swollenness of the battery was the first thing they noticed not having diagnosed it yet. Have no clue why it would swell up like that, never dropped it, never got water on it as far as I can recall in the almost 3 years I have owned it.

Comment: It's a 2015 model - 5 years is a good life for a battery, no matter how well-kept.